# CombineLatest, execute only once after all observables are complete

Tags: angular, typescript, combinelatest

I'm trying to solve an issue. Currently, I'm opening a modal but I needed the combination of the 3 route **observables** for this. So, my code logic is something like this:

```
combineLatest([obs1, obs2, obs3])
    .subscribe(([s1, s2, s3]: any) => { 
        openModal();
    });
```

Since it will get executed 3 times, my modal will also be opened three times but I don't want it to do that but I know is expected behavior.

So, for this, the **bad solution** I implemented was using a `flag` like this:

```
let shouldOpen = true;

combineLatest([obs1, obs2, obs3])
    .subscribe(([s1, s2, s3]: any) => { 
        if(shouldOpen) {
            shouldOpen = false;
            openModal();
        }
    });
```

But of course, that's not a good solution.

So, the **question** is, Is there a way for me to keep using `combineLatest` but getting it executed **only once**?

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-9xvuuq?file=index.ts) if you want to try with combineLatest.

> Note: I cannot use `forkJoin` or `zip`, I already tried those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can't use `forkJoin` (which is the right answer), skip the first two emissions from the `combineLatest`

```
combineLatest([obs1, obs2, obs3])
  .pipe(skip(2))
  .subscribe(([s1, s2, s3]: any) => { 
    openModal();
  });
```

You could also use `skipWhile` to skip until all three are defined:

```
      .pipe(skipWhile(([s1, s2, s3]) => s1===undefined || s2 === undefined || s3===undefined))
```

Comment: Since the complexity of my project is very high, I cannot use forkJoin because it'll carry out a huge refactor because if I use it, it breaks a lot of code, that's why I'm asking for a solution using only combineLatest.

Comment: See reply. My second answer is less elegant, but should work, and only open the modal the one time.

Comment: Wouldn't you also add a `take(1)`, just to be sure?

Comment: You could also add a take(1) too. Good idea.